# "import serial" fails with Python 3.3.2, pyserial 2.5

Tags: python-3.3, pyserial

I am having a problem with "import "serial".

I am running Python 3.3.2 on Windows (XP) and have installed pyserial 2.5 from the Windows installer pyserial-2.5.win32.exe. The traceback below shows what happens.

```
C:\hal\Python>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]  on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from serialwin32 import *
ImportError: No module named 'serialwin32'
>>>
```

The python interpreter finds and runs c:\python33\lib\site-packages\serial\ __init__.py, which checks the os name, finds that it is "nt" and executes "from serialwin32 import *". That fails.

The file serialwin32.py is in the \serial directory with __init__.py.

I tried this with Python 3.1.1 and 3.2.3 and got the same results.

I read that pyserial 2.5 is not dependent on pywin32 but I have it installed anyway; win32, build 18, for Python 3.3.

Has anyone seen this problem or know what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks